# Git TFS Visual Studio showing pending changes when there are none

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, git-tfs

I have just cloned a repository and the under the included changes panel in Visual Studio there were 100+ changes being detected. I did a `git reset --hard` and that dropped the changes to about 20.

I've also tried the `git --reset hard HEAD` variant. I've also tried `git stash git stash drop` and `git checkout .` A diff on the files shows they haven't been changed.

Does anyone know how I might reconcile the false changes or why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you sure they are false? Newline changes, tab change etc may not appear in a diff but they *are* changes nonetheless

Comment: It's possible it could be the encoding, I'll pull it up in another diff tool to see if I can see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to line endings. See [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) for dealing with them.

Thanks to @Panagiotis Kanavos